# Can't call parameter from function

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

My app has build field when i call a function.
It show Mach-O Linker Error.
Where did i make any mistake?

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
    ScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-88)];
    ScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*13, self.view.frame.size.height-88);
    [self.view addSubview:ScrollView];

    arrImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"image-001", @"image-002", nil];

    LoadImage:(1);
}

-(void)LoadImage:(int *)index;
{
    ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-88)];

    [ImageView setImage:[arrImages objectAtIndex:index]];
    [ScrollView addSubview:ImageView];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
LoadImage:(1);
```

should be:

```
[self LoadImage:1];
```

Also, your `LoadImage:` method should take a parameter of type `int`, not `int *`.

These are some really basic mistakes. May I suggest you take some time to learn the basics of Objective-C.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I just start learning iOS and i know i need to learn more. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
LoadImage:(1);  // <--- error

[self LoadImage:1]; // <--- like that
```

Edit:
As @Till pointed out, also change your declaration to take an int:

In header (.h):

```
-(void)LoadImage:(int)index;
```

In implementation (.m):

```
-(void)LoadImage:(int)index { //<--- lose that semi-colon
...
}
```

All those fix-ups should do the trick

Comment: Check again - LoadImage expects a pointer to an int!

Comment: Additionally, call [super viewDidAppear:animated] in your viewDidAppear method; and it is strongly recommended that you start all of your methods with a lowercase letter.  So rename to "loadImage".

Comment: @Till - ah, that's true as well, though he's using it as an int.

Comment: Also - as with methods, by convention your variables should start with a lowercase letter.  Change `ImageView` to `imageView` to make your code more readable for others.

Comment: @Dave, thanks for your help. I'm new in iOS. I need to learn more. Thanks  you.

Comment: No problem, looks like you're pretty close to getting it.  PS: same note about your "ScrollView" variable... - wink.

Comment: @rmaddy - heh; had to type really quickly to get that answer posted before you. :)